# Python Separating string with Regex

Tags: python, regex

This is my string:

```
st = "$10,8001st$6,480,2nd$2,160,3rd$1,188,4th$648,5th$324"
```

My Expected output is:

```
$10,800 1st $6,480, 2nd $2,160, 3rd $1,188, 4th $648, 5th $324
```

I write this code:

```
result = " ".join(re.split("([\$\d\,]+)\d[a-zA-z]{2}", st))
```

But output not satisfy me, coz, it removes some part.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: `$444th` should give `$44 4th` or `$4 44th`?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to stack overflow, the problem is not with the python but with your regexp expression, I recommend you to use sites like regex101 for testing such cases. Take a look https://regex101.com/r/l7wrb3/1 as you see last part is not parsed as part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
text = "$10,8001st$6,480,2nd$2,160,3rd$1,188,4th$648,5th$324"
print(" ".join(re.split(r'(\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*,?)', text)).strip())
# => $10,800 1st $6,480, 2nd $2,160, 3rd $1,188, 4th $648, 5th $324
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4iAXQU) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WynQM/1). The pattern is a single capturing group (so that `re.split` could output the captured strings, too) that matches

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0 or more occurrences of `,` followed with three digits
- `,?` - an optional `,`.